# How to create logical constraints for a hierarchical tree in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, hierarchical-data

I have created a hierarchical tree to represent the organization chart of a company on Neo4j, which is like the picture below.

[Hierarchical Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlAd5.png)

Each node can't have more than one incoming "Manage relation" and an employee can't manage someone who is his hierarchical superior.

I have seen that Neo4j has a system of constraint, but I still have two problems without answers.

- How to prevent the Worker6 node from having a Manage relationship with the Worker1 node for example?
- How the check this integrity constraint during an import with a CSV?

Should I use TransactionEventHandler to do that ?

Comment: How are identified workers  who couldn't be directly managed by the boss ? Maybe the response can be found with labels.

Comment: My problem is not only with the boss, but with all superiors. My tree has a lot of level and not only three. So I don't think than labels can resolve my problem

Comment: You should look into [Triggers](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/). Neo4j doesn't really have traditional db triggers yet, but it does have event handlers that are close to it. You should be able to use a before commit hook to throw away the transaction if it tries to make an illegal  data value. Otherwise, you might have to just use Neo4j's version of stored procedures to enforce the logic.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. When you said stored procedure, you speak about this procedure [Conditional Cypher Execution](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_conditional_cypher_execution) ? 
Do you know if triggers are triggered when I do a load with a csv ?

Answer (score 0):

I have find how to create logical constraints for my hierarchical tree.

When I want to import a file of 50 000 relationships, I do this request :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///dump.csv" AS row
MERGE (a:Person {name:row.person1Name})
MERGE(b:Person {name:row.person2Name})
FOREACH (t in CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS((a)-[*]->(b)) THEN [1] ELSE [] END |
    MERGE (a)-[pr:Managed]->(b))
```

With this request I can check the integrity of my tree.

My biggest problem is still the slowness of the request  : 3m20 for 50 000 relationship